# Checking and using two arrays in loops

Tags: java, loops

Is there any way to simplify the following code. How it is roughly set up is it's scanning for a value, though if the input throws an exception, it needs to say nonono and reask for the value. I need to collect both values x and y like this so then I can operate on them in a scientific calculator way. Having the inputted string "RESULT" = the answer of the previous calculation is a requirement. These two loops that ask for x and y are so similar, with only "first operand" and "x = answer", and "second operand" and "y = answer" being different. So is there any way I can optimize this code so that there is only one loop needed since both are so similar? Here's the code.

```
    String operand;
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;

    //These two arrays are the differences between both of the loops that follow. Everything besides first, x and second, y are the same
    String arr[] = {"first", "second"};
    Double var[] = {x, y};

    boolean operandLoop1 = false;
    //x
    while (!operandLoop1) {
        System.out.print("Enter " + arr[0] + " operand: ");
        operand = calcOption.next(); // retrieve first value
        if (operand.equals("RESULT")) {
            var[0] = answer; // If I want to use the previous result as my input
            operandLoop1 = true;
        } else {
            try {
                var[0] = Double.parseDouble(operand); // Assumes that if it isn't RESULT, then I'll want to put in a number
                operandLoop1 = true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { // necessary if I type anything else in besides RESULT and a double
                System.out.print("Error: Invalid input! Correct inputs are any real number and \"RESULT\"!");
            }
        }
    }

    boolean operandLoop2 = false;
    //y
    while (!operandLoop2) {
        System.out.print("Enter" + arr[1] + " operand: ");
        operand = calcOption.next(); // retrieve second value
        if (operand.equals("RESULT")) {
            var[1] = answer; // If I want to use the previous result as my input
            operandLoop2 = true;
        } else {
            try {
                var[1] = Double.parseDouble(operand); // Assumes that if it isn't RESULT, then I'll want to put in a number
                operandLoop2 = true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { // necessary if I type anything else in besides RESULT and a double
                System.out.print("Error: Invalid input! Correct inputs are any real number and \"RESULT\"!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Apologies about the length, but hopefully I can get it approximately half in length.

Comment: If the code works, please head over to ask at [codereview.se].

Comment: Write a method which performs the operation you need, seed it with the values which change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the only difference between the two sections is the array index, you can use a for loop, as follows:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    boolean operandLoop = false;
    while (!operandLoop) {
        System.out.print("Enter " + arr[i] + " operand: ");
        operand = calcOption.next(); // retrieve value
        if (operand.equals("RESULT")) {
            var[i] = answer; // If I want to use the previous result as my input
            operandLoop = true;
        } else {
            try {
                var[i] = Double.parseDouble(operand); // Assumes that if it isn't RESULT, then I'll want to put in a number
                operandLoop = true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { // necessary if I type anything else in besides RESULT and a double
                System.out.print("Error: Invalid input! Correct inputs are any real number and \"RESULT\"!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also make it a method, passing in the parameters for `calcOption`, `answer`, and the ordinal (`arr[0]`), and replacing all of the assignments for `var[0]` with return statements. I don't know the type of `calcOption`, but it would look something like this:

```
Double methodName(Object calcOption, Double answer, String ordinal) {
    boolean operandLoop = false;
    while (!operandLoop) {
        System.out.print("Enter " + ordinal + " operand: ");
        String operand = calcOption.next(); // retrieve value
        if (operand.equals("RESULT")) {
            return answer; // If I want to use the previous result as my input
        } else {
            try {
                return Double.parseDouble(operand); // Assumes that if it isn't RESULT, then I'll want to put in a number
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { // necessary if I type anything else in besides RESULT and a double
                throw new RuntimeException("Error: Invalid input! Correct inputs are any real number and \"RESULT\"!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```